# Riemann tensors in 3 dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

So in 3 dimensions, Riemann tensor has 6 independent terms. So we can fully describe it in terms of the Ricci tensor.

> How do I show that $R_{abcd}=T_{ac}g_{bd}+T_{bd}g_{ac}-T_{ad}g_{bc}-T_{bc}g_{ad}$
>   for $$T_{ab}=R_{ab}-\frac{R}{4}g_{ab}?$$

What I thought:
I know that $R_{ab}=g^{mn}R_{namb}=g^{mn}(T_{nm}g_{ab}+T_{ab}g_{nm}-T_{nb}g_{am}-T_{am}g_{nb})$, but how do I continue from here?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind But I think this is a useful topic, since I couldn't find anywhere where this identity is explicitly derived